# How to fit image inside StackFit.expand?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to fit image completely inside stack.Currently using Stackfit.expand

But I am unable to fill red portions.

I've tried using Boxfit all methods but still not getting the desired output

[image]

Code:

```
GridView.count(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      childAspectRatio: 0.75,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
children: List.generate(
          10,
          (index) {
        
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
          },
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 7.5, 0, 7.5),
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        getModuleImageAssest(item),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    // bottom: 20,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    top: 150,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        "Data",
                        maxLines: 2,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'MedusaGothic',
                            foreground: Paint()
                              ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
                              ..strokeWidth = 1
                              ..color = Colors.white,
                            // decoration: TextDecoration.,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            // color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )),
        );
      }),
```

I've tried using several boxfit methods

Also tried container's boxdecoration's image param but still not getting desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

#### Using NetworkImage

```
 GridView.count(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  childAspectRatio: 0.75,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: List.generate(
    10,
    (index) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 7.5, 0, 7.5),
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                // bottom: 20,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 150,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "Data",
                    maxLines: 2,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'MedusaGothic',
                      foreground: Paint()
                        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
                        ..strokeWidth = 1
                        ..color = Colors.white,
                      // decoration: TextDecoration.,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      // color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Result-> [image]

#### Using AssetImage

```
GridView.count(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    childAspectRatio: 0.75,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: List.generate(
      10,
      (index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 7.5, 0, 7.5),
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/tiger.jpg',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  // bottom: 20,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  top: 150,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Data",
                      maxLines: 2,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'MedusaGothic',
                        foreground: Paint()
                          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
                          ..strokeWidth = 1
                          ..color = Colors.white,
                        // decoration: TextDecoration.,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        // color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Result-> [image]

#### Updated Answer as per @Pacific requirnment

```
 GridView.count(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    childAspectRatio: 0.75,
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    children: List.generate(
      10,
      (index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 7.5, 0, 7.5),
            child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: AssetImage(
                        'assets/my_club.png',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  // bottom: 20,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  top: 150,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Text(
                      "Data",
                      maxLines: 2,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'MedusaGothic',
                        foreground: Paint()
                          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
                          ..strokeWidth = 1
                          ..color = Colors.white,
                        // decoration: TextDecoration.,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        // color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Result-> [image]