# How to set 3 row widget as 3 column in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the output that i want

[image]

here is what my output is

[image]

here is the code

```
ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final data = diseaseList[index];
              return     Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 25, left: 25, bottom: 15),
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    DiseaseCard(
                      sectionName: data.diseaseName,
                      image: data.image,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
            
            },
            itemCount: diseaseList.length,
          )
```

how to get exact output like this in flutter???

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656642/13997210) answer and set  the given property `crossAxisCount: 3,` instead of _2_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: title,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text(title),),
    body: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: List.generate(100, (index) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            'Item $index',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
          ),
        );
      }),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter provides a straightforward [class](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/grid-lists) for this, with which you can create a GridView.